# Which visualization is better for large and multidimensional data

Tags: jquery, charts, data-visualization, large-data

I am facing a problem to visualize some data with the help of charts/graphs. 
My Data has 3 dimensions

1. Marketplaces (MP)
2. Items
3. Daily sales

I want to plot a chart which tell me the daily frequency of each item sold in each market place. If I plot the data in table it will be as follows

```
MP  |   Item    | Date  | Units Sold
X   |   a       |20-Mar | 3
X   |   b       |20-Mar | 2
Y   |   c       |20-Mar | 4
Y   |   a       |20-Mar | 2
Z   |   e       |20-Mar | 6
X   |   a       |21-Mar | 2
X   |   b       |21-Mar | 5
Y   |   c       |21-Mar | 1
Y   |   a       |21-Mar | 0
Z   |   e       |21-Mar | 3
```

I have multiple marketplaces (more than 15) , multiple items (more than 50), and each item has some sales or 0 sale daily in each market place. I uses line charts, there were a lot of lines, it was a mess and hard to understand, same for the stacked bar charts. I cannot cover each dimension in stacked bar chart.

Can you suggest me which type of visualization should I use that would be easy to understand and cover each dimension. I am using jQuery D3 for visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check stock chart by amcharts: http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/ it supports multiple panels which can be used to visualize different  dimensions and you can use a separate dataset for each item - this will allow users to select which items he wants to see at a time.

Disclaimer: I am the author of amcharts.